# program does not contain a static 'Main' method

Tags: c#, xml, http-post, dotnet-httpclient

How can I make an HTTP XML POST request and send data to url to get responce?
And I am trying sample too, but VS giving error in below sample:

`CS5001 Program does not contain a static 'Main' method`

```
public class Program
 {
    static HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
    private static HttpResponseMessage response;

    static async Task Main()
    {
    HttpContent content = new StringContent("Hello Google.com"); 
    content.Headers.Add("SecreteCode", "Anything");
     
    response = await httpClient.PostAsync("https://google.com/", content);
    string responseText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    Console.WriteLine(responseText);
    }
}
```

What could be wrong in code?

Comment: This compiles and runs successfully on my side. Not using Visual Studio, but `csc.exe -reference:System.Net.Http.dll Program.cs` after calling `VsDevCmd.bat` on the console. Maybe there's something wrong with the project type, build output type, or startup project of your Visual Studio project?

Comment: @skreutzer no, nothing wrong with the project type, I tried everything but useless(((

Comment: As https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs5001 suggests, you did check for the C# target version to be >= 7.1?